# Can see a file in Docker container, but cannot access it

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and ran into the following problem:

In my Dodckerfile I have these lines:

```
ADD dir/archive.tgz /dir/
RUN tar -xzf /dir/archive2.tar.gz -C /dir/
RUN ls -l /dir/
RUN ls -l /dir/dir1/
```

The first ls prints out files correctly and I can see that dir1 was created inside dir by the archive, with permissions drwxr-xr-x. But the second ls gives me:
ls: "cannot access /dir/dir1/: No such file or directory"

I thought that if the Docker can see a file, it can access it. Do I need to do some special magic here?

Comment: Can you add to the question the permissions of those files?

Comment: do `dir1` exists? Update question and Put your whole working dockerfile (excluding prats not important in this question) which allow us to reproduce problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu the permissions for dir1 are -rwxr-xr-x.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski the dockerfile downloads lots of tars and unzips them. This cannot be reproduced by someone else as the tars are not public. Yes, dir1 exists, as I can see it in the printout of the first ls.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I added some more details

Comment: Could you create a container and check the files there?: `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash <container>`

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu sorry I don't know Docker well enough. What should I put instead of <container> - can this be any name? And what do I do with it after it's created?

Comment: After you build it shows and long id, that should used as <container>. It will show you a prompt, do a *ls* and check if the files are accesible.

Comment: @user2199745 comment out the RUN line causing error. Then `cd application_dir; docker build . `. Now launch a container  as suggested by @GonzaloMatheu, replacing <container> with the output of `docker images -q | head -1`

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu thanks, got it! I did this, then ls -l and can see dir1 with drwxr-xr-x. I also see the files inside dir1.

Comment: @Timir thanks, I managed to have a look inside the container and can see the directory and the files in it.

Comment: is dir1 a directory? `-rwxr-xr-x.` denotes a file, directories start with `d`.

Comment: @Mark yes sorry that was a typo. In the question itself I put the right permissions, they start with a 'd'.

Comment: Do those commands work on your computer? (Replacing /dir by a temp dir). Could you add add an excerpt of `tar -tf archive2.tar.gz`?

Comment: The ADD command uses `archive.tgz` and the RUN uses `archive2.tar.gz`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu no, there is one archive inside the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that if the Docker can see a file, it can access it.

- In a way you are right, but also missing a piece of info. Those RUN commands are not necessarily sequentially executed since docker operates in layers, and your third RUN command is executed while your first might be skipped. In order to preserve proper execution order you need to put them in same RUN command as such so they end up on the same layer (and are updated together):

  ```
  RUN tar -xzf /dir/archive2.tar.gz -C /dir/ && \
      ls -l /dir/ && \
      ls -l /dir/dir1/
  ```

  This is common issue, most often when this is put in Dockerfile:

  ```
  RUN apt-get update
  RUN apt-get install some-package
  ```

  Instead of this:

  ```
  RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get install some-package
  ```

Note: This is in line with best practices for usage of RUN command in Dockerfile, documented here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run and avoids possible confusion with caches/layes...

To recreate your problem here is small test to resemble similar setup to yours, depending on actual directory structure in your archive this may differ:

- Dummy archive 2 with dir/dir1/somefile.txt created:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/test-sowf/dir/dir1 && cd ~/test-sowf && echo "Yay" | tee --append dir/dir1/somefile.txt && tar cvzf archive2.tar.gz dir && rm -rf dir
  ```
- Dockerfile created in ~/test-sowf with following content

  ```
  from ubuntu:latest
  COPY archive2.tar.gz /dir/
  RUN tar xvzf /dir/archive2.tar.gz -C /dir/ && \
      ls -l /dir/ && \
      ls -l /dir/dir/dir1/
  ```
- Build command like so:

  ```
  docker build -t test-sowf .
  ```
- Gives following result:

  ```
  Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
  Step 1/3 : from ubuntu:latest
  ---> 452a96d81c30
  Step 2/3 : COPY archive2.tar.gz /dir/
  ---> Using cache
  ---> 852ef4f706d3
  Step 3/3 : RUN tar xvzf /dir/archive2.tar.gz -C /dir/ &&     ls -l    /dir/ &&     ls -l /dir/dir/dir1/
  ---> Running in b2ab281190a2
  dir/
  dir/dir1/
  dir/dir1/somefile.txt
  total 8
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  177 May 10 15:43 archive2.tar.gz
  drwxr-xr-x 3 1000 1000 4096 May 10 15:43 dir
  total 4
  -rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 4 May 10 15:43 somefile.txt
  Removing intermediate container b2ab281190a2
  ---> 05b7dfe52e36
  Successfully built 05b7dfe52e36
  Successfully tagged test-sowf:latest
  ```
- Note that extracted files are with 1000:1000 as opposed to root:root for the archive, so unless you are not running from some other user (non root) you should not have problems with user, but, depending on your archive you might run into path problems (/dir/dir/dir1 as shown here).
- test that file is correct, and contains 'Yay' inside:

  ```
  docker run --rm --name test-sowf test-sowf:latest cat /dir/dir/dir1/somefile.txt
  ```
- clean the test mess afterwards (deliberatelynot using rm -rf but cleaning individual files):

  ```
  docker rmi test-sowf && cd && rm ~/test-sowf/archive2.tar.gz && rm ~/test-sowf/Dockerfile && rmdir ~/test-sowf
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue, but I have a new clue. I'll post it as an update to the question.

Comment: This is not correct. The best practice is to get thiner layers or make it more readable not because of the execution order. In `apt` example causes errors due to outdated indexes on docker cached layer.

Comment: Yes, rather clumsy explanation, I'll update to make it more clear (url given below gives more details).

Answer (score 0):

For those using docker-compose:

Sometimes when you volume mount a folder/file from one container to another before it exists, it can have weird permissions after it's created

For example if one container is [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) and another is your webserver, certbot will take time to generate the  /etc/letsencrypt folder and its contents

From the webserver you might be able to see the folder or its contents with an `ls`, but not open them. You can see the behavior with a `cat *` and you'll get back

`cat: <files in question>: No such file or directory`

One solution is generating the folder at build time with a `RUN mkdir -p /directory/of/choice` in your dockerfile for the container generating the folder/files. Then the folder will exist and docker will happily mount it to your other container or host machine the way you want it to